# как правильно объявить глобальные переменные?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь сделать файл настроек (colors.py) Суть в том чтобы при смене значения "THEME = " переменным присваивалось определенное значение. в данном случае все красиво, но пишет что переменная не является глобальной, ссылаться каждый раз именно на эту функцию не вариант. объявлять каждую переменную через global еще то занятие... подскажите как правильно и попроще прописать все переменные?

```
THEME = "Light"           # Light, Dark, WLight, WDark
ICONS = "Colors"          # Colors, Monochrome

def Light():
    # главные цвета программы
    color_background = "#F2F2F2"
    color_background_hover = "#E5E5E5"
    color_border = "#666666"
    # цвета иконки перемещения
    color_label = "#333333"
    color_label_hover = "#666666"
    # цвета иконок главного меню
    if   ICONS == "Colors":       color_icon = "#3497D8"; color_icon_select = "#ff6a00";
    elif ICONS == "Monochrome":   color_icon = "#333333"; color_icon_select = "#00000000";
    # цвета подгрупп
    color_group_background = "#F2F2F2"
    color_group_border = "#D3D3D3"
    color_group_border_hover = "#B6B6B6"
    # цвета контекстного меню
    color_context_background = "#FFFFFF"
    color_context_background_hover = "#333333"
    color_context_border = "#333333"

def Dark():
...
def WLight():
...
def WDark():
...

if   THEME == "Light":   Light()
elif THEME == "Dark":    Dark()
elif THEME == "WLight":  WLight()
elif THEME == "WDark":   WDark()
```

Вопрос решил очередным if:

```
# Настройки цветов
THEME = "Light"           # Light, Dark, WLight, WDark
ICONS = "Colors"          # Colors, Monochrome

if   THEME == "Light":
    # главные цвета программы
    color_background = "#F2F2F2"
    color_background_hover = "#E5E5E5"
    color_border = "#666666"
    # цвета иконки перемещения
    color_label = "#333333"
    color_label_hover = "#666666"
    # цвета иконок главного меню
    if   ICONS == "Colors":       color_icon = "#3497D8"; color_icon_select = "#ff6a00";
    elif ICONS == "Monochrome":   color_icon = "#333333"; color_icon_select = "#00000000";
    # цвета подгрупп
    color_group_background = "#F2F2F2"
    color_group_border = "#D3D3D3"
    color_group_border_hover = "#B6B6B6"
    # цвета контекстного меню
    color_context_background = "#FFFFFF"
    color_context_background_hover = "#333333"
    color_context_border = "#333333"
    print ("Light")

elif THEME == "Dark":
...

elif THEME == "WLight":
...

elif THEME == "WDark":
...
```

### Дополнительный вопрос 2:

не получается встроить динамическое изменение темы при нажатии на кнопку,
и как правильно импортировать в icon.py?

файл main.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QFrame, QLabel, QMenu
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtSvg import QSvgWidget, QSvgRenderer

class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
# --- Основное Окно Программы ---
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.mwidget = QMainWindow(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Tool | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 100, 200, 200))

        self.pbx1 = QPushButton(self)
        self.pbx1.setObjectName("pbx1")
        self.pbx1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1, 15, 45, 45))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("G4.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pbx1.setIcon(icon)
        self.pbx1.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.pbx1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.setTheme(themes.ThemeDark))

# --- Показать Окно ---
        self.show()

    def setTheme(Theme):
        theme=Theme

# --- Запуск Окна Программы ---
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import themes
    theme=themes.ThemeLight
    button=themes.ButtonColors
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)   
    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

файл themes.py

```
class ThemeLight:
    # главные цвета программы
    color_background = "#F2F2F2"
    color_background_hover = "#E5E5E5"
    color_border = "#666666"
    # цвета иконки перемещения
    color_label = "#333333"
    color_label_hover = "#666666"
    # цвета подгрупп
    color_group_background = "#F2F2F2"
    color_group_border = "#D3D3D3"
    color_group_border_hover = "#B6B6B6"
    # цвета контекстного меню
    color_context_background = "#FFFFFF"
    color_context_background_hover = "#333333"
    color_context_border = "#333333"

class ThemeDark:
    color_background = "#000000"
    # ...

class ThemeWLight:
    color_background = ""
    # ...

class ThemeWDark:
    color_background = ""
    # ...

class ButtonColors:
    color_icon = "#3497D8"
    color_icon_select = "#ff6a00"

class ButtonMonochrome:
    color_icon = "#333333"
    color_icon_select = "#00000000"
```

файл icons.py

```
import themes
theme=themes.ThemeLight

CL    =   theme.color_label

# Иконка Label вертикальная
icon_label_vertical = """
<svg>
<path fill="%s" opacity="1.00" d=" M 154.00 14.00 C 158.66 14.00 163.33 14.00 168.00 14.00 C 167.99 18.67 168.00 23.33 168.00 28.00 C 163.33 28.00 158.67 28.00 154.00 28.00 C 153.99 23.33 154.00 18.67 154.00 14.00 Z" />
</svg>""" % CL
```

при нажатии на кнопку:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

### Дополнительный вопрос 3:

Почему не меняет цвет setStyleSheet?

themes.py:

```
class ThemeLight:
    test = "#FF0000"

class ThemeDark:
    test = "#00FF00"
```

main.py:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QFrame, QLabel, QMenu
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtSvg import QSvgWidget, QSvgRenderer
import icons, themes

class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):

# --- Основное Окно Программы ---
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.mwidget = QMainWindow(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Tool | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 100, 200, 200))
        self.setStyleSheet("""
                  QFrame#frame {
                      background-color: %s;
                  }          
            """ % theme.test)

        self.frame = QFrame(self)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 200, 200))

        print (theme.test)

        self.pbx1 = QPushButton(self)
        self.pbx1.setObjectName("pbx1")
        self.pbx1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1, 15, 45, 45))
        self.pbx1.clicked.connect(lambda: setTheme(themes.ThemeDark))

# --- Показать Окно ---
        self.show()

def setTheme(Theme):
    theme=Theme
    print (theme.test)

# --- Запуск Окна Программы ---
if __name__ == "__main__":
    theme=themes.ThemeLight
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)   
    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `Вопрос решил очередным if:` только это не позволит динамически менять переменные. Кст, а те переменные где используются? Есть в setStyleSheet, то можно было через QApplication менять стили, т.е. без кучи переменных и с мгновенным результатом

Comment: Солидарен с комментарием @gil9red , но использовать в PyQt5 `global` не стал бы никогда.

Comment: @gil9red, это позволит менять по крайней мере перед запуском программы. можно и такой пример увидеть? да, именно там и используются (для конкретных элементов и для всего окна)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Объявляете глобальные переменные вне функций:

```
color_background = ""
color_background_hover = ""
color_border = ""
...
def Light():
...
```

2) Внутри функций, где будете менять значения глобальных переменных первой строкой пишите `global <переменная>`:

```
...
def Light():
   global color_background, color_background_hover, ...

...
```

3) Теперь, все присваивания глобальным переменным изменят их

```
def Light():
   global color_background, color_background_hover, ...
   color_background = "#F2F2F2"
...
```

---

Пример реализации через классы.

Класс `Theme` базовый класс, который содержит все поля, а все остальные наследуются от `Theme` либо от его потомков, переписывая поля под свою тему:

```
class Theme:
    # главные цвета программы
    color_background = ''
    color_background_hover = ''
    color_border = ''
    # цвета иконки перемещения
    color_label = ""
    color_label_hover = ""
    # цвета иконок главного меню
    color_icon = ''
    color_icon_select = ''
    ...


class ThemeLight(Theme):
    color_background = "#F2F2F2"
    color_background_hover = "#E5E5E5"
    color_border = "#666666"
    ...


class ThemeLightColors(ThemeLight):
    # color_background и остальные переменные уже определены в ThemeLight
    color_icon = "#3497D8"
    color_icon_select = "#ff6a00"
    ...


class ThemeLightMonochrome(ThemeLight):
    # color_background и остальные переменные уже определены в ThemeLight
    color_icon = "#333333"
    color_icon_select = "#00000000"
    ...
```

Использование:

```
# Создавать объект не нужно -- поля объявлены у самого класса
theme = ThemeLightColors
print(theme.color_background)
print(theme.color_icon)
print(theme.color_icon_select)
# #F2F2F2
# #3497D8
# #ff6a00

# Поэтому можно и так:
print(ThemeLightColors.color_background)
print(ThemeLightColors.color_icon)
print(ThemeLightColors.color_icon_select)
# #F2F2F2
# #3497D8
# #ff6a00

# Пример функции, принимающей темы
def set_theme(theme: Theme):
    print(theme.color_background)
    print(theme.color_icon)
    print(theme.color_icon_select)
    ...

set_theme(ThemeLightColors)
set_theme(ThemeLightMonochrome)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99961/discussion-on-answer-by-gil9red-----).

Answer (score 0):

**Ответ на дополнительный вопрос #3**

Потому, что у вас `setStyleSheet` отрабатывается только один раз -- для одного стиля, а вызывать нужно при каждой смене темы:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QFrame, QLabel, QMenu
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtSvg import QSvgWidget, QSvgRenderer
import icons, themes

class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):

# --- Основное Окно Программы ---
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.mwidget = QMainWindow(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Tool | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 100, 200, 200))

        self.frame = QFrame(self)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 200, 200))

        # Применение дефолтной темы
        self.setTheme(themes.ThemeLight)

        self.pbx1 = QPushButton(self)
        self.pbx1.setObjectName("pbx1")
        self.pbx1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1, 15, 45, 45))
        self.pbx1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.setTheme(themes.ThemeDark))

# --- Показать Окно ---
        self.show()

    def setTheme(self, theme):
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QFrame#frame {
                background-color: %s;
            }          
        """ % theme.test)

# --- Запуск Окна Программы ---
if __name__ == "__main__":
    theme=themes.ThemeLight
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)   
    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```